# How do you use the 'files' and 'directories' properties in package.json?

Tags: npm, package.json

If a `package.json` has a `files` prop, and/or a `directories` prop:

```
  "files": [
    "./src/assets/fonts/"
  ],
  "directories": {
     "assets:": "./src/assets"
  }
```

What are some ways to make use of them? The documentation does not mention what can be done with them once they have been specified.

For example, the [files docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) say:

> The "files" field is an array of files to include in your project. If you name a folder in the array, then it will also include the files inside that folder.

What does "include in your project" mean? Include where? How are they accesible now that they weren't before?

In the [directories section](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#directories), the docs say:

> In the future, this information may be used in **other** creative ways.

What are the existing creative ways it is being used?

Comment: Unfortunately in the JavaScript world, things like "_File patterns follow a similar syntax to .gitignore, but reversed_" is all the documentation you're going to get.  How similar, I wonder?  You would normally expect to find a grammar, or at least reference to some other specification as to how the value is interpreted.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

"include in your project" means the files will be in the packaged tarball that is created when you run `npm publish`. You can also run `npm pack` to generate the tarball for inspection without actually triggering a publish. This way you can actually open the generated tarball and inspect which files were/were not included.

While `.npmignore` (or `.gitignore` as a proxy, if no `.npmignore`) functions as a black list of files to ignore (thereby including everything else by default), the `files` array is a whitelist. That is, instead of including everything by default, if `files` array is specified everything is excluded by default and only those files explicitly listed will be included in the packaged tarball.

As an example, say your package is a library meant for consumption in the browser. Your code is in `lib/`, and you run browserify to compile into a browser-compatible lib at `dist/index.js`. You start out with a bunch of files listed in `.gitignore`, which is used as the defacto `.npmignore` which doesn't exist. But now that `dist/` is full of generated files, you want them ignored from the git repo. If you add them to `.gitignore`, they will be excluded from the git repo, *but they will also be ignored from the package tarball*. So you have two options: duplicate your `.gitignore` as `.npmignore` but only list `dist/` in `.gitignore`. If you do this, you will have to keep two files almost-but-not-quite in sync. This way is tedius and error-prone.

The other alternative is to not have a `.npmignore`, and instead just list the files you actually want in the package, in the `files` array. `README.*`, `package.json`, `CHANGELOG.*` (maybe a couple others) are automatically included in the tarball regardless. So you simply add `"files": [ "dist" ]` and you're done. Now your package tarball won't include original source JS from `lib`, nor `tests/` etc but will instead only contain the actual compiled lib in `dist/`.

As for `directories`, I typically list the `lib` (for es5), `src` (for es6, coffeescript, typescript etc sources), `dist` (for browser or vm-specific builds), `test`, `output` (for temporary generated files like coverage reports, etc), `doc`, etc. Though this property isn't used directly by npm or other tools, it makes the directory structure explicit. Also, it makes the directories referenceable in npm scripts like so:

```js
"scripts": {
  "clean": "rm -rf $npm_package_directories_dist $npm_package_directories_output",
  "lint": "eslint $npm_package_directories_src",
  "test": "teenytest $npm_package_directories_test",
}
```

In this way, the directories are specified only once, and if they change, they only need changed in a single location (rather than many throughout the package.json).

Comment: for me files are displayed in tarball contents but not available in node-mosules folder. Do you know what can be the issue ?

Comment: You can also now do `npm publish --dry-run` to find out exactly which files are included without doing the actual publish step